# how to show hand cursor on a button which is inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a button which is inside div

```css
.calculateActivityBtn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="calculateActivityBtn">
    <div class="pagination centered">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" id="getFilesButton" title="<%= language['UI.reports.tooltip.getFilesButton'] %>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats">button text</i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i hover on the div it gives me a hand cursor in chrome, but in firefox it does not show me a hand cursor till the pointer reaches the button icon .

I have tried changing **z-index** of the two div's and changing **cursor:pointer** in css.

**I want a hand cursor when hovered on the div also in firefox.**

Comment: in your code, which you share here with us, there is no `cursor:pointer;` or what so ever if I hover no matter in which browser. Can you please update your question so we can at least reproduce what you describe?

Comment: Just a `cursor: pointer;` should do the trick in any browser.

Comment: @Joschi is there some other way to put cursor:pointer ?

Comment: @Pri_stack Not sure because this always works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Padding` instead of `margin` in `pagination div`..
check updated snippet...

```css
.calculateActivityBtn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculateActivityBtn">
    <div class="pagination centered">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" id="getFilesButton" title="<%= language['UI.reports.tooltip.getFilesButton'] %>">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats">button text</i>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.pagination:hover #getFilesButton{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

and be sure to support any specific browser for 
browser support about cursor you can check it here

[Caniuse cursor supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-cursors)

Hope, it will work. let me know if you need more help

Comment: check  `  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;`  and if you have z-index property try to remove and see console if it has width, height. if still not working share your snippet clearly.